# When ssh to remote host, how can I know the bash pid running on remote host?

Tags: ssh, bash, pid

When I ssh to a remote host, Is it possible that I get the remote bash pid in my local machine? or vice versa?

for example on local terminal, I simply do ssh and keep connection to run my tasks:

```
ssh user@remote.com
```

and the ps is like this on local machine:

```
ps faux
...
shunh    32683  0.1  0.0 121148  5116 pts/2    Ss   07:02   0:00  \_ -bash
shunh    33079  0.6  0.0 189360  8484 pts/2    S+   07:03   0:00      \_ ssh -X remote_host
```

and on remote_host:

```
ps faux
...
root     214679  0.0  0.0 158820  5724 ?        Ss   07:03   0:00  \_ sshd: shunh [priv]
shunh    214681  0.0  0.0 158820  2556 ?        S    07:03   0:00      \_ sshd: shunh@pts/1
shunh    214682  0.0  0.0 121124  3608 pts/1    Ss   07:03   0:00          \_ -bash
```

So can I get the pid number "214682" in my local machine?

Comment: The question is very strange. A direct, exact and completely useless answer would be: "ssh remote.system echo \$\$", which will print on local stdout a pid that bash had when it started on connection. That bash is immediately exited. But, why you want that pid? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

## Simply

As [@Nikita Kipriyanov commented](https://serverfault.com/posts/comments/1282416), the simple way is

```
ssh user@remote.domain 'echo $$'
```

(using single quotes!), But seem not really usefull, because *localhost* will be able of reading process number only after they finish.

## Use case:

There is some way of running `ssh` in order to foward ports, for sample: this will connect *`indirRem.remDom:22`* via ssh proxy: *`user@rem.dom`*.

```
ssh -f -L2022:indirRem.remDom:22 user@rem.dom 'echo $$ $PPID;sleep 2' >/tmp/rpids.txt &&
    ssh -o HostKeyAlias=indirectRemote.remotedomain -p 2022 indUser@localhost
```

From there, if on localhost, you hit something like:

```
ssh user@rem.dom ps ef $(</tmp/rpids.txt)
```

You may see wich pid is used for current (open) session (while you don't close/end shell session on *`indirRem.remDom:22`*).

## Mariadb/Mysql sample:

```
ssh -f -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@rem.dom 'echo $$ $PPID;sleep 2' >/tmp/rpids.txt &&
    mariadb -h 127.0.0.1 -p"What a strong password" database
```

This will locally run `mariadb` client on local `3306` tcp port, but this port is a forwarded port from *`rem.dom`* (wich is normally listenning on loopback device only)

Same but forwarding *UNIX socket* instead of TCP service:

```
ssh -f -L 3306:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock user@rem.dom 'echo $$ $PPID;sleep 2' >/tmp/rpids.txt &&
    mariadb -h 127.0.0.1 -p"What a strong password" database
```

Then

```
ssh user@rem.dom ps ef $(</tmp/rpids.txt)
```

will show the `sshd` process who hold forwarded ports.

## But

Anyway, I don't see what to do with this *`/tmp/rpids.txt`*.

Read `man ssh` and `man sshd`, look for `-M` (master) and `-S` (slave) switches.